Which direction does the current go?

We have two circle-shaped sets of wire. In the beginning, theres no current in either of them. Now we put current into the left(or right, doesnt matter) circuit. Which direction does the inducted voltage/current want to go? The same, as in both (counter) clockwise, or opposite directions? Based on faradays and lenz laws, it should go the way which prevents the original force. But which is it then?

If the lenz rule only affects the direction that opposes the change in external flux through the loop , then isnt this kind of incompatible with following case, where the coil is long enough to be considered a straight wire?


did you do any calculations? usually, these problems are best solved by doing the math.

The thing is, there is no specified data values and it should be something "obvious, the solution being direct result of a law of some sort and requiring little to no math calculations if any" according to the person who have shown me this exercise, but ever since i came across this exercise i still cannot figure it out.  As in one of these either is stronger in EVERY scenario, or maybe no current gets inducted due to both of these being equal?

We are not given neither size, resistance, radius or distance between both of the coils. (All the data given is in the post already)

Or maybe its derived from an integral of some sort, which im may not know (but i couldnt find anything about it)

you don't need to know the specific numerical values of any of these quantities, as long as you know how they enter the equations. Either way, to have induction, you need a time-varying magnetic field, which in turn requires a time-varying current.

It is , time varying: t=0, b1=0, t>0, b1>0. It changes in a single point of time, generating a voltage-spike, unless i am wrong?

Lenz's law says that the induced current in a loop will flow in the direction that opposes the change in external flux through the loop.  So if the right-hand loop is closed at the bottom, then it's the direction of the external magnetic field through the loop that matters, not the magnetic field at some point outside of the loop.

Consider the flux change, $\Delta \Phi_{2,1}$, through 2 due to current change in 1. Here it will help to think about the shape and direction of the (closed loop) field lines produced by 1. Lenz's law tells us that the flux, $\Phi_{2,2}$, through 2 due to induced current in 2 will be in the opposite direction to $\Delta \Phi_{2,1}$. This gives you the direction of the induced current in 2.

So your top two ring-and-dot (approaching arrowhead) symbols are irrelevant, because they don't concern field lines going through coil 2.

It would be a solution for sure, but it seems counter intuitive (see at: last edit/ https://i.sstatic.net/2fFLf6XM.png ) @philip-wood

Sorry, but I can't follow your reasoning. Incidentally, if the current is increasing in the direction you've shown in your left hand coil, then the induced current in the right hand coil is in the opposite direction from the one you've shown.
